# Implementing Delayed_Job for long running create and update actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, unicorn

Rails 3.2 / Ruby 2.1 / Unicorn running on Heroku w/2 web dynos

I've been running into some issues of the app timing out when I'm creating / updating records. This only appears to happen in the Production environment and generally happening when I'm on a slow connection. I'm wondering if setting up a worker dyno and adding DelayedJob to handle the create/update actions would be a good solution?

**Products Controler Create & Update**

```
  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to manage_products_path, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to manage_products_path, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the app timing out"? Is Heroku killing a long-running request, or is your browser timing out? If it's the former, your connection speed shouldn't matter. What do your `create` and `update` methods look like? DelayedJob might be a solution, but it depends on where the slowdown is. Have you profiled those methods?

Comment: Sorry, yes, Heroku is killing a long-running request. The create/update methods are pretty standard, nothing special going on. However, these do involve nested forms.

Comment: Please post your `create` and `update` code. If they're "pretty standard" they shouldn't be taking long enough for Heroku to kill them.

Comment: Added. Let me know if there is any additional code you'd like to see, the models, forms, controllers, etc.

Comment: Please add the model